# Dialog with primeVue get the wrong row data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, primevue

I'm working on creating a table that features a kebab menu in each row. When you click the 'Update' button, a dialog box opens, displaying the data from the current row. However, for some reason that I can't understand (Maybe something related to the refs) the data always corresponds to the last row. This issue persists even when I create a new row. When I click 'Update' on any other row, it still attempts to update the most recently added row(that is the last one in the table), and I don't understand why."

Here is the code:

```js
<template>
  <div class="purposes">
    <h1>This is the Purposes page</h1>
    <Button label="Create" icon="pi pi-plus" @click="openDialog(null)"></Button>
    <Dialog v-model:visible="showDialog" modal header="Header">
      <template #header>
        <h2 v-if="isUpdateMode">Update Purpose</h2>
        <h2 v-else>Create Purpose</h2>
      </template>
      <InputText v-model="currentPurpose.name" placeholder="Name" />
      <InputText v-model="currentPurpose.key" placeholder="Key" />
      <InputText v-model="currentPurpose.terms" placeholder="Terms" />
      <Button
        v-if="isUpdateMode"
        label="Update"
        icon="pi pi-refresh"
        @click="updatePurpose"
      ></Button>
      <Button v-else label="Save" icon="pi pi-check" @click="createPurpose"></Button>
    </Dialog>
    <Card class="rounded-card">
      <template #content>
        <DataTable :value="purposes">
          <Column field="id" header="ID"></Column>
          <Column field="name" header="Name"></Column>
          <Column field="key" header="Key"></Column>
          <Column field="terms" header="Terms"></Column>
          <Column>
            <template #body="slotProps">
              <Button
                icon="pi pi-ellipsis-v"
                class="p-button-rounded p-button-text"
                @click="menu.toggle($event, slotProps.data)"
              ></Button>
              <Menu :model="menuItems(slotProps.data)" ref="menu" popup />
            </template>
          </Column>
        </DataTable>
      </template>
    </Card>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import type { Purpose, CreateOrUpdatePurpose } from '@/types/global'
import {
  fetchPurposes,
  createOrUpdatePurpose as createOrUpdatePurposeAPI
} from '@/api/purposesService'

const purposes = ref<Purpose[]>([])
const menu = ref<any>(null)
const showDialog = ref(false)
const currentPurpose = ref<CreateOrUpdatePurpose>({
  id: null,
  name: '',
  key: '',
  terms: ''
})
const isUpdateMode = ref(false)

const menuItems = (purpose: Purpose) => [
  {
    label: 'Update',
    icon: 'pi pi-refresh',
    command: () => {
      console.log('Clicked update for: ', purpose) // Log here
      openDialog(purpose)
    }
  }
]

onMounted(async () => {
  try {
    const data = await fetchPurposes()
    if (data) {
      purposes.value = data
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred while fetching purposes:', error)
  }
})

const openDialog = (purpose: Purpose | null) => {
  console.log('Purpose in openDialog: ', purpose) // Log here
  if (purpose) {
    isUpdateMode.value = true
    currentPurpose.value = { ...purpose }
  } else {
    isUpdateMode.value = false
    currentPurpose.value = { name: '', key: '', terms: '' }
  }
  console.log('CurrentPurpose after update: ', currentPurpose.value) // Log here
  console.log('Is update mode: ', isUpdateMode.value) // Log here
  showDialog.value = true
}

const createPurpose = async () => {
  try {
    const createdPurpose = await createOrUpdatePurposeAPI(currentPurpose.value)
    purposes.value.push(createdPurpose)
    showDialog.value = false
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred while creating the purpose:', error)
  }
}

const updatePurpose = async () => {
  try {
    const updatedPurpose = await createOrUpdatePurposeAPI(currentPurpose.value)
    const index = purposes.value.findIndex((p) => p.id === updatedPurpose.id)
    if (index !== -1) {
      purposes.value[index] = updatedPurpose
    }
    showDialog.value = false
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred while updating the purpose:', error)
  }
}
```

The console.log at menuItems have already the wrong purpose in it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

on the button instead of the `@click="menu.toggle($event, slotProps.data)"`
put `console.log(slotProps.data)` and check if the result still be the last row data or not.